# Cloud run connect devices Cloud IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a IoT architecture which I have differents devices sending info to Google Cloud using MQTT. I am in a dev enviorement and I don'r have the real devices so I am trying to simulate them with a Cloud Run (Just try to connect using de rsa keys and python code).

The problem is that my cloud run doesn't work, the devices don't connect and I don't have a specific error, for example I test the same code with cloud functions and any problem.

Does cloud run have some problem with IoT core service? or expose something in my docker?
I tried the port 8883 and 433

Comment: Can you share your errors and some piece of code?

Comment: I followed the sample code step by step and it works in my localhost. Definitely my problem is cloud run but I am not sure how to fix it or if I have to add something in the dockerfile.

Comment: Which code sample? Can you provide us more inputs to help you more and to reproduce your case?